# Need to create a special regex that detects all possible phone number formats

Tags: regex, phone-number

Need a regex that can sift through walls of texts in excel and pick up numbers. Each cell in excel sheet has at least 200-1500 characters with lots of numbers in them so i can't use [^0-9\n] as it simply places all digits together

I need a regex that can detect these phone number patterns and remove everything else

> xxx-xxx-xxxx
>   xxxxxxxxxx
>   +xxx+xxx+xxxx+

Basically, where the + (plus)  sign is, there can be ANY special characters including space key or letter that can be found in the keyboard or out if possible. Example

> 555a451%6454
>   555/444-1211<
>   5554445552
>   15424331336
>   1-524l654-3211
>   (424) 525-5455
>   (424) 5424522
>   Etc

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
[a-z\%\/\-\(\)\s]?\d{3}[a-z\%\/\-\(\)\s]?\d{3}[a-z\%\/\-\(\)\s]?\d{4}[a-z\%\/\-\(\)\s]?
```

`[a-z\%\/\-\(\)\s]` this part is allowed char that means your special char.

[live demo](https://regex101.com/r/wA8wT1/1)

Comment: thanks, but now when i replace all only the above regex strings are removed. anyway to remove all text besides the phone numbers?